# Colocar imagem no Picker Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Como faço para colocar uma imagem ao lado direito do `Picker` (DropDownList) para que dê para diferenciar dos outros campos `Entry`, para ter uma aparência de um objeto de seleção ?

```
<Picker x:Name="picTpEndereco" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Title="Tipo de Endereço" SelectedIndex="{Binding EndTipo}">
  <Picker.Items>
     <x:String>Comercial</x:String>
     <x:String>Residencial</x:String>
     <x:String>Outro</x:String>
  </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, AndreeH.

Com o Picker padrão você não irá conseguir. Você vai precisar desenvolver um Bindable Picker para poder ter o efeito que deseja. Eu pessoalmente nunca fiz um picker que utilize imagem, porém posso indicar esse post do [StudyXnet](http://studyxnet.com.br/xamarin-forms/binding-picker/) que fala sobre bindable Picker.

Depois posta pro pessoal ai se você conseguiu.